# Linking errors when building with clang++ with C++11 flag enabled on OSX 64bit

Tags: c++11, boost, clang++

I have a code that was compiling ok with old C++ standard and it still compiles ok when passing -stdlib=libc++ and -std=c++11 to clang++ but the build fails on linking stage.

Snippet of an error I'm getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::operator bool() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libcontrol_slib.a(Request.o)
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in libcontrol_slib.a(LogUtils.o)
  "std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::gptr() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::underflow() in libcontrol_slib.a(LogUtils.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::pbackfail(int) in libcontrol_slib.a(LogUtils.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::overflow(int) in libcontrol_slib.a(LogUtils.o)
      std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::seekoff(long long, std::__1::ios_base::seekdir, unsigned int) in libcontrol_slib.a(LogUtils.o)
```

When running:
nm LogUtils.o | c++filt | grep U

I can indeed see the unresolved function `std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::operator bool() const`:

```
U std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::operator bool() const
```

When running nm on libc++ confirm that this function is not present there.

Im using other libraries that I rebuild with c++11 switch on and linking with the new stdlib (unless I missed something) that I'm linking with - one of them is boost library.

The questions I would like to ask:

1. Why compiler is trying to link with non existing libc++ functions?
2. What could possibly be causing it?

Comment: Probably a clang bug like [this](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/LIBCPP-INLINE-VISIBILITY-and-std-string-length-td4030879.html).